# How to show fixed items in listview and remaining in scrolldown

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView with a Adapter class extending BaseAdapter. My Adapter class returns entire list items. But I want to limit the item count. And Remaining items need to be shown when doing scroll. So for that I tried below in Adapter class,

```
@Override
public int getCount(){
return 5;
}
```

But it returns only 5 items only.

Hardcoding the layout height is also one solution. But I don't want to hardcode height.

***For displaying search results, I'm using ListView. Search result is ListView item. I have more number of search results. So ListView is occupying entire screen according to the search results. I just want to display 5 results and remaining need to be displayed when doing scrolling***

So how can I achieve it without hardcoding?

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you need, the listview itself takes care of show items remaining on scroll, or you need to know how many items are show on the screen?

Comment: @javdromero Usecase: For displaying search results, I'm using ListView. Search result is ListView item. I have more number of search results. So ListView is occupying entire screen according to the search results. I just want to display 5 results and remaining need to be displayed when doing scrolling.